# Eye Blink Detection in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Can't find any implementation/package anything related blink detection in flutter, if anyone implemented please share.
Eye blink detection in flutter any package idea? or I have to do it in native? any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's OpenCV package along many others to detect eye movements/blinking and then integrate it with flutter

Once you consume the video feed,

```
EYE_AR_THRESH = 0.3   

for rect in rects:
    # determine the facial landmarks for the face region, then
    # convert the facial landmark (x, y)-coordinates to a NumPy
    # array
    shape = predictor(gray, rect)
    shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)
    # extract the left and right eye coordinates, then use the
    # coordinates to compute the eye aspect ratio for both eyes
    leftEye = shape[lStart:lEnd]
    rightEye = shape[rStart:rEnd]
    # EAR = eye aspect ratio
    leftEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(leftEye)                     # important line
    rightEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(rightEye)                   # important line
    # average the eye aspect ratio together for both eyes
    ear = (leftEAR + rightEAR) / 2.0
```

The var 'ear' gives eye aspect ratio. Now, you compare if it is below the threshold.

```
if ear < EYE_AR_THRESH:
    # eye is blinked. continue with your business logic.
```

I do think this would be the easiest and most effective method

For more info please visit [this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/24/eye-blink-detection-opencv-python-dlib/) on eye-tracking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how can I integrate it with flutter?

Comment: Do you still need help with this question?

Answer (score 1):

For flutter, I found solution for eye blink detection through using [Firebase ML](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit).
for this I had to use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_camera_ml_vision)

It has face detector feature which include 'eye open probability'. Thus solve the problem. For details check the package.

```
FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector().processImage
```

You can check package and its example through git repo.

**comment here if anyone face any problem.**

Comment: Hi! Can you share project's codes? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can find/train a Tensor Flow model and convert it into a .tflite model along with a .txt file which contains the list of classes.

You can then use [tflite](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite) package to use model.

For getting the results from image stream Use it with the [camera 0.5.8+2](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) plugin.

```
await cameraController.startImageStream((CameraImage img) {
    var recognitions = await Tflite.runModelOnFrame(
    bytesList: img.planes.map((plane) {return plane.bytes;}).toList(),// required
    imageHeight: img.height,
    imageWidth: img.width,
    imageMean: 127.5,   // defaults to 127.5
    imageStd: 127.5,    // defaults to 127.5
    rotation: 90,       // defaults to 90, Android only
    numResults: 2,      // defaults to 5
    threshold: 0.1,     // defaults to 0.1
    asynch: true        // defaults to true
    );

print(recognitions);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this